# What's the conditional probability of a word based on the previous word in a text for each word

Tags: probability

I'm kind of lost on this.

Let's say we have a long text, something like 800 words. Some repeated, some not.

Based on the previous word(I'm guessing that means if we know the previous word) what's the conditional probability of the next word?

Using: $P(A|B) = P(AB)/P(B)$

I've been thinking, that P(AB) is how many times a combination of words was used in a text, and P(B) tells me how many times the previous word in each combination of words has been used.

To put this into perspective and a smaller example.

Let's say we have this:

> A small dog jumped over the fence. The dog used its small paws to jump over the fence. The fence was no challenge.

Let's ignore if the sentence is grammatically correct. What are the conditional probabilities of each word, if we know the previous word?

There are 22 words in this example.

Using my logic:

$$P(small|a) = P("a\; small") / P(a) = ("1/22") / ("1/22") = 1 $$

This is obviously very wrong. Or is it ? I'm honestly torn between: We've analyzed the text and obviously every time there was the word a it was followed by small. Therefore we can safely assume with 100% certainty.

However, knowing myself, every time I've reached conclusions like these I was very wrong and since I'm currently ahead of my school work I have no one to discuss this over and I would appreciate any help or ideas you may throw at me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $X_n$ denote the $n$-th word. Then in your simple model (technically speaking, assuing we're using a [Markov chain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_chain)) then for words $x,y$

$$P(X_{n+1} = y | X_n = x) = \frac{\#\{\text{occurences of } x \text{ followed by } y\} }{\#\{\text{occurences of } x \}},
$$

In your example since there is only one occurence of "a small", and also only one occurence of the word "a", we have

$$P(X_{n+1} = \text{"small"} \, | \, X_{n} = \text{"a"} ) = \frac11 = 1.
$$

Suppose instead we were using the sentence "a small man had a llama, but the tall woman had a small alpaca.". Then in this context, the generic formula above gives:

$$P(X_{n+1} = \text{"small"} \, | \, X_{n} = \text{"a"} ) = \frac{2}{3}.
$$

Unlike the original poster's solution, this does not depend on the total length of the sentence for the calculation (in this case $14$ words), but only the relative frequency of the pair "a small", to the single word "a".

**Update. The case that the sentence ends in $x$**

In the model described above, it is possible that $\sum_y P(X_{n+1} = y \, | \, X_n = x) < 1$, which occurs in the case that the sentence ends in the word $x$.

Consider for instance the sentence: "a small man had a llama called a". In this case our calculation gives:

$$P(X_{n+1} = \text{"small"} \, | \, X_{n} = \text{"a"} ) = P(X_{n+1} = \text{"llama"} \, | \, X_{n} = \text{"a"} )= \frac{1}{3}.
$$

but there are no other words that follow "a" in the passage. This is because we also have the probability of $1/3$ that "a" is not followed by another word. In the contexts of Markov chains this is known as an absorbing state.

Suppose we want to rule out this case, then the suitable formula is:

$$P(X_{n+1} = y | X_n = x) = \frac{\#\{\text{occurences of } x \text{ followed by } y\} }{\#\{\text{occurences of } x \text{ followed by another word}\}},
$$

In the last example ("a small man had a llama called a"), the denominator is now equal to 2 (since we ignore the last a), and we get the expected probability of $1/2$ that "a" is followed by "small".

**Update. Why this disagrees with the original poster, and @Thomas Pastor**

In the original post it is suggested that

$$P(\text{"a"}) = 1/22$$

because there are $22$ words, and $a$ appears once. However, it is also suggested that

$$P(\text{"a small"}) = 1/22$$
presumably for the same logic that there are $22$ words and "a small" appears once. However this should be counted in pairs of successive words, of which there are only 21, so this would be:

$$P(\text{"a small"}) = 1/21$$

With this `correction', the original poster's method would give:

$$P(\text{"a small"}\,|\, \text{"a"} ) = \frac{22}{21} > 1,$$
which is clearly not possible.

This was then formalized in the post of @Thomas Pastor as:

\begin{align*}
P(X_{n+1} = y \, | X_n =x) & = \frac{P(X_n = x,\, X_{n+1} =y )}{P(X_n = x)} \\
& = \frac{\#\{\text{occurrences of x followed by y}\}  \#\{\text{words}\}}{
\#\{\text{occurrences of x}\}  \#\{\text{pairs of words}\}}
\end{align*}
The issue with this formula is that it does not account for the case that $x$ may be the last word of the sentence. In particular, note that if we sum this formula over all words $y$, we get:

\begin{align*}
\sum_{y} P(X_{n+1} = y \, | \, X_n = x) & =
\sum_y \frac{\#\{\text{occ. of x followed by y}\}  \#\{\text{words}\}}{
\#\{\text{occ. of x}\}  \#\{\text{pairs of words}\}} \\
& =\frac{ \#\{\text{words}\}}{
\#\{\text{occ. of x}\}  \#\{\text{pairs of words}\}}
\sum_y \#\{\text{occ. of x followed by y}\} \\
\end{align*}

If it is the case that $x$ is not the last word in the sentence, then the summation on the right hand side is equal to $\#\{\text{occ. of x}\}$ from which we would get:
\begin{align*}
\sum_{y} P(X_{n+1} = y \, | \, X_n = x) & =
\frac{ \#\{\text{words}\}}{\#\{\text{pairs of words}\}} \\
& > 1.
\end{align*}

So the discrepancy is caused by how to handle the special case of the last word.

Comment: Except the Markov chain concept, your probability formula is identical to what the OP has done.

Comment: @ThomasPastor, see my update above. I disagree that this is equivalent to the original poster's model.

Comment: Oh so we're just taking into consideration the occurences of xy and x? Is it really irrelevant the size of the whole text?  How come we're using P(X) and not P(Y) as the conditional probability formula would suggest?

Comment: The length of the text will have an impact: but only as it makes occurrences of the word "a" more likely, and (if real text) less likely that it would be followed by "small". On your second comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean about using $P(X)$ not $P(Y)$. Perhaps this is just that we are using different notation? We are dividing the number of occurrences of both words "a small" by the number of occurrences of the first word "a".

Comment: @owen88 Using which definition of Markov chain that you have this formula based on ONLY the number of occurence if you **consider the sample size of numerator and denomator are different** ?

$$P(X_{n+1} = y | X_n = x) = \frac{\#\{\text{occurences of } x \text{ followed by } y\} }{\#\{\text{occurences of } x \}}$$

The model which is called Markov chain is defined by the defintion

$$P[X_{n+1} = y | X_n = x, X_{n-1}=z, X_{n-2}=t, ...] = P[X_{n+1} = y | X_n = x])$$

Comment: and by using Bayesian conditional probability 
$$P[X_{n+1} = y | X_n = x]) = \frac{P[X_{n+1} = y \textrm{ AND } X_n = x])}{P[X_n = x]}$$

This is what the OP has used.

And by taking the definition of empirical probability 

$$P[X_{n+1} = y \textrm{ AND } X_n = x]) = \frac{\#\{\text{occurences of } x \text{ followed by } y\}}{\textrm{#pairs of successive words}}$$

$$P[X_n = x] = \frac{\#\{\text{occurences of } x \}}{\textrm{#words}}$$

Comment: As I put in my (edited) post, yesterday: this does not give the same number, since $\#\{\text{pairs of successive words}\} \neq \#\{\text{words}\}$. In particular, when you sum over all options $y$, you would need (for this to be a probability measure): $\sum_y P(X_{n+1} = y \, | X_n = x) = 1$, however your formula gives $N/(N-1)$, where $N$ is the total number of words.

Comment: @owen88 of course it does not work because of the way you calculate the probability of the pair of words. Indeed, if "a small" happens at $x_n$ and $x_{n+1}$, the probability "a small" happens at $x_{n+1}$ and $x_{n+2}$ is 0. The events are not independent. The formula of the author of the question is ok, just the application is wrong.

Comment: This still does not explain why the formula as you / poster stated adds to greater than 1, which is not anything to do with independence: it violates the law of total probability. I have explained in the post that this is due to handling the final word of the sentence.

Comment: @owen88 because when you (and the author) derive the probabilites by counting the number of occurence is correct is only when the sample size is large and the occurence are independent. Both of you calculated wrong numbers then unsurprisingly the final result was wrong. Think about this, if in your sentence whenever we see "a", we are sure to have "a small", are the probability of "a" and "small" still identical, and is the probability of "a" is still the number of occurence divided by the length of the sentence ?

Comment: @Thomas Pastor, I still don't understand your reasoning for saying the answer is wrong. If you mean "in the real world, the probability that the word " a" is followed by "small"", then you are correct: the estimate here is clearly wrong. However, based on a mathematical model, and the information available, this is a standard approach assuming a Markov structure...

Comment: ... If you have the time, I'd be interested to see a detailed explanation of why you think the solution I provide is wrong, why you think it is equivalent, and an example making it clear that it is incorrect. Also, I'd be interested in seeing an example of how you would calculate this probability... All of which is too  much for the size of comments!

Answer (score 0):

What is your question ?

What you are doing is [Empirical distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empirical_distribution_function) and it converges to the real distribution when your sample size is large enough. You got the "seems wrong" result because your sentence is short.